# Go - Non blocking way of locking mutex

Tags: go, locking, mutex

I have a simple usecase where I want to lock a mutex, and rather than blocking the goroutine on the *locked mutex* it should simply return **false** or an **error**.

```
if mutex.lock() {
    // successful lock
} else {
    // locking failed, already locked
}
```

is there any existing *pkg* supporting this use case or any *easy* way of achieving this, preferably without using any external lib?

Comment: maybe you could try a cas write; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap but i would use a channel and a select.

Comment: @mh-cbon an example of channel with select would be useful.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488475/5728991 answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón. thats what exactly I was looking for.